# How can I check if an attribute is present in CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Is it possible to define CanCan ability for, let's say, users with `organisation_id  != nil` via hash conditions?

```
can :crud, User, :organisation_id => ?present?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. This will only allow users with non null organization_id to do crud

```
can :crud, User.all do |user|
  user.organization_id.present?
end
```

Comment: Well, that's not a hash condition. :(

In block condition form I think it should start with `can :crud, User, ["users.organization_id IS NOT NULL"] do |user|` to allow correct fetches.

Comment: Why do you want it to be a hash if you can get the same result by doing it other ways

Comment: I'm just trying to find some cleaner way to do it. But currently it looks like using block is the only way...

Comment: @Vimsha The block form doesn't work with `#accessible_by` for loading in an index/collection action.

Comment: @graywh It does if you specify SQL for fetching records, as I noted in first comment, still, it's quite ugly for such simple condition.